Powershell script with phispy: file does not exist
I have been working on a bioinformatics project with PhiSpy via Powershell and have written a .ps1 script to try and batch process some genomes (downloaded from NCBI). Last night the script worked fine, but now it keeps telling me the files I'm trying to access don't exist.
$dir = Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\GCA_001929*"    # working directory is the parent of all folders containing .fna files
foreach ($i in $dir){        # loop through a small number of subdirectories (7)
    cd $i
    phispy *.fna -o .\       # each directory has a single .fna file
    cd ..
}

For every file I want to access, the terminal throws this error:
phispy: error: argument infile: Checking for validity: *.fna does not exist
(PS I know there are slightly redundant parts of the code; they weren't like that before but I put them in today when the errors started appearing to try and work around them)
The odd thing is, when I get the script to list the *.fna files, it recognises the files normally:
foreach ($i in $dir){
    ls $i\*.fna
}

Directory: C:\Genome_assemblies\PhiSpy\ncbi_dataset\data\unprocessed_xoo\Xoo_complete\ncbi_dataset\data\GCA_001929245.2

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                  
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                  
-a----        02/09/2024     12:24        5157185 GCA_001929245.2_ASM192924v2_genomic.fna               

for all the directories matching $dir.
As a last resort, I could do it one at a time but there are so many genomes to process and each one takes quite a while so would like to avoid that.
Any tips?

Pass the full path of each file:
Get-ChildItem -Directory ".\GCA_001929*" |Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.fna |ForEach-Object {
    phispy $_.FullName -o "$($_.DirectoryName.TrimEnd('\'))\"
}

The FullName property contains the full path to the file, whereas DirectoryName resolves that file's parent directory path - by passing both paths explicitly there's no longer any need to change location with cd all the time
